# Truck won't start unless I jump it (and I've replaced the battery)

Tags: ford, battery, starting, f-150

I drove my 2009 f150 platinum to work one morning with no issues. As I was trying to start it to go home, the engine did nothing. All the lights and so forth worked just fine, but I didn't even hear the a click when I turned the key. We jumpstarted it after a few minutes and no issues driving home. The next morning it was doing the same thing. I assumed the battery was done, so I got a new one. Trouble is, the new battery is doing the exact same thing.

I'm baffled.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Do the lights go out when you go to start the truck?

Comment: The dash and radio go out, but the low-beams and interior lighting stayed on.

Comment: Does the truck use a key or a push button start? I'm assuming a key? I'm wondering if there's a problem with the ignition. If it is a key, you may try turning the key to the start position several times in quick succession to see if it sparked the starter.

Comment: verify that your check engine light is going out while you are in the cranking position.